# Parser error for ASP.net in Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: asp.net, excel

When I add "Project/Add References..."

Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library

Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library

I get an parser error for "Excel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
instead of Version 12.0.

Here is my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'From Excel
    Dim exlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim exlWb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim exlWs As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Arr(25, 25), j, k
    exlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    exlWb = exlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\path\file1.xlsm")
    exlWs = exlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    exlWb.Activate()
    For k = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 3
            Arr(j, k) = exlWs.Cells(j + 1, k + 2)
        Next j
    Next k
    exlWb.Close()
    exlWs = Nothing
    exlWb = Nothing
    exlApp.Quit()
    exlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Error code:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application' from assembly 'Excel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The type is marked as eligible for type equivalence, but the containing assembly is not loaded as fully trusted.
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office Interop is NOT SUPPORTED for use with server side, such as ASP.NET. You need to find an alternate solution. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) by Microsoft.